# How to change save location of screenshot using com.google.android.libraries.cloudtesting.screenshots.ScreenShotter

Tags: android, screenshot, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I followed this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/test-screenshots

However, looking at the source code for ScreenShotter:

```
private static final String SCREENSHOT_PATH = "/sdcard/screenshots/";
....
File imageFolder = new File("/sdcard/screenshots/");
```

`/sdcard/screenshots/` is the default location and there is no way to change that.

Currently I get this log error:

`E/cloud_screenshotter: Exception taking screenshot: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/screenshots/<package>.MockTest-testFilterButton-isPageShown-1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I am trying to test on a real device that does not have a sdcard slot so I want to save it to internal storage.

How can I change the location? Or can I only use cloudtestingscreenshotter_lib.aar library with firebase test lab?

Comment: `/sdcard` is (should be) available on every device, even if there's no explicit sdcard slot. Each Android device has a storage area that maps to `/sdcard`. I've not encountered a device that does not have it. Can you check the following: a) Your test package has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, b) The folder is created `adb shell ls /sdcard`, you should see a folder named `screenshots`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve it @nommer? I have write/read storage permissions and it still didn't help.

Comment: sorry I have not had a chance to try the solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the rules for writing to external storage changed with Android 10 (API 29). https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
But as Maik noted, you should be OK if your app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.